# What is it in me(sentence meaning)

Tags: sentence-meaning

What is the meaning of:

> **What is it in me**....(ex.what is it in me that is holding me back)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There, **in me** refers to some aspect of your personality or psyche.

What personality trait, or what aspect of my psychology, is the obstacle that keeps me from progressing.